# A surprising difference between pandas.Timestamp and Python datetime. (Should I submit a bug to pandas team ?)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, timezone-offset

here is the problem : pandas.Timestamp answer differ from Python datetime answer.
More precisely, given a "naive" date d, I build dt, an "aware" datetime (python) and ts, an "aware" Timestamp (pandas) both with timezone="Europe/Paris".
I was expecting both timezone offset to be the same.
But pandas says 2 hours, and Python says 1 hour.
So ??
Important : this occurs only for some precise date-time :
I scan all dates with step one hour, from 2010-01-01 02:00:00 until now() and find exactly the same problem to those dates (and only those)

```
d=2010-10-31 02:00:00
d=2011-10-30 02:00:00
d=2012-10-28 02:00:00
d=2013-10-27 02:00:00
d=2014-10-26 02:00:00
d=2015-10-25 02:00:00
d=2016-10-30 02:00:00
d=2017-10-29 02:00:00
d=2018-10-28 02:00:00
d=2019-10-27 02:00:00
d=2020-10-25 02:00:00
d=2021-10-31 02:00:00
d=2022-10-30 02:00:00
```

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz
import pandas as pd

d = '2022-10-30 02:00:00'

ts = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(pd.Timestamp(d))
dt = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(parser.parse(d))

print(ts)  # ts is a pd.Timestamp
2022-10-30 02:00:00+02:00
#                    ^

print(dt)  # dt is a datetime.datetime
2022-10-30 02:00:00+01:00
#                    ^

pd.show_versions()
/Users/puiseux/opt/miniconda3/envs/python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py:33: UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.
  warnings.warn("Setuptools is replacing distutils.")
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : 2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5
python           : 3.11.0.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Darwin
OS-release       : 21.6.0
Version          : Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Thu Sep 29 20:12:57 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.240.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
machine          : x86_64
processor        : i386
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : None
LOCALE           : fr_FR.UTF-8
pandas           : 1.5.3
numpy            : 1.24.2
pytz             : 2022.7.1
dateutil         : 2.8.2
setuptools       : 65.5.0
pip              : 22.2.2
Cython           : None
pytest           : None
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : None
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : None
lxml.etree       : None
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 3.1.2
IPython          : None
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : None
bottleneck       : None
brotli           : None
fastparquet      : None
fsspec           : None
gcsfs            : None
matplotlib       : 3.7.0
numba            : None
numexpr          : None
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : None
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : 11.0.0
pyreadstat       : None
pyxlsb           : None
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.10.0
snappy           : None
sqlalchemy       : 2.0.4
tables           : None
tabulate         : 0.9.0
xarray           : None
xlrd             : None
xlwt             : None
zstandard        : None
tzdata           : 2022.7
```

Comment: `2022-10-30 02:00:00` is a [DST transition](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2022), i.e. it could fall on both UTC+1 *and* UTC+2 (it's ambiguous). Try calling `pd.Timestamp(d, tz='Europe/Paris')` ...

Comment: This is the same problem (which is not) for `'2022-03-27 02:00:00'`.

Comment: @FObersteiner. No you can't because it doesn't work for `'2022-03-27 02:00:00'`. (NonExistentTimeError)

Comment: `pd.Timestamp(d, tz='Europe/Paris')` lead to the following exception :`pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2022-10-30 02:00:00, try using the 'ambiguous' argument`
but i can't find any parameter named 'ambiguous' in pytz ...

Comment: @Corralien that's exactly what I wanted to point out ;-) If you set the timezone as in the OP, and it does *not* raise an error, it's arbitrary if the result will fall on UTC+1 or UTC+2.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug in pandas, nor pytz. As pointed out in the comments, 2022-10-30 02:00:00 falls into a DST transition, i.e. it could be both UTC+1 or UTC+2.

However, you can define into which period the result should fall.

With pandas, set the `ambiguous` keyword in [tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) - Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

t = '2022-10-30 02:00:00'

print(pd.Timestamp(t).tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous=True)) # DST
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+02:00

print(pd.Timestamp(t).tz_localize('Europe/Paris', ambiguous=False)) # no DST
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+01:00
```

With `pytz`, you'd use the `is_dst` keyword:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

t = '2022-10-30 02:00:00'

print(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(datetime.fromisoformat(t), is_dst=True))
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+02:00

print(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris').localize(datetime.fromisoformat(t), is_dst=False))
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+01:00
```

And since `pytz` is deprecated, finally with `zoneinfo` you'd use `fold`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

print(datetime.fromisoformat(t).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris')).replace(fold=0))
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+02:00

print(datetime.fromisoformat(t).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Paris')).replace(fold=1))
# 2022-10-30 02:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Thank you FObersteiner, your answers are bright !